# No Artwork Available iphone build for ios6

Tags: cordova

The iPhone  Application has icon.png in Resource folder. when i execute my application on iPhone device the icon is available, but if i make build and drag into iTunes. it has no icon. I am using Xcode 4.5 iOS 6. How to fix this issues?

Thanks in advance for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is fixed (by providing a default) in 2.2.0
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1482

You can probably copy stuff from https://github.com/brion/incubator-cordova-ios/commit/c0c345389336381c5e1e8306ecbe560201267f8c